# Use relative column name value to calculate DATE value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

I have a table that has some peculiar data arrangements where there are 28-31 columns corresponding with the day of the month for a series of unique IDs. What I'm trying to do is bring that into a more feasible format with actual date values. My tables look something such as below:

```
DECLARE @Month VARCHAR(3) 
SET @Month = 'NOV'
```

| ID | Status | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | Active | A | 2 | 3 | 4 | Z |
| 222 | Inactive | Z | 5 | f | 6 | 7 |

I'd like ideally to have a way to convert this into something like the below:

| ID | Status | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | Active | 11/1/2022 | A |
| 111 | Active | 11/2/2022 | 2 |
| 111 | Active | 11/3/2022 | 3 |
| 111 | Active | 11/4/2022 | 4 |
| 111 | Active | 11/5/2022 | Z |
| 222 | Inactive | 11/1/2022 | Z |
| 222 | Inactive | 11/2/2022 | 5 |
| 222 | Inactive | 11/3/2022 | f |
| 222 | Inactive | 11/4/2022 | 6 |
| 222 | Inactive | 11/5/2022 | 7 |

An approach that is flexible as to the number of columns, with respect to different number of days in the month, would be preferable with some minor considerations to performance.

Comment: What is the source of the month value in your table?

Comment: I suggest you use a calendar table. This is a table with one record per day. There are many online examples of how to create. Then you join your table to this table on month/year. This for example turns one row into 28 rows for Feb. Then you use case statements to pivot

Comment: The source of the month value will be within a separate file that will be processed alongside the specific table. The table itself is coming from a CSV file.

Comment: Seems like you'll going to need a dynamic unpivot here, if I am honest. If you could fix the source data, that would very likely be the *far* better option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to use JSON to "dynamically" unpivot your data

```
Select A.[ID]
      ,A.[Status]
      ,[Date] = datefromparts(2022,11,[key])
      ,Value
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply  (
                 Select [Key]
                       ,[Value]
                  From  OpenJson(  (Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper )  ) 
                  Where [Key] not in ('ID','Status')
              ) B
```

**Results**

```
ID  Status  Date        Value
111 Active  2022-11-01  A
111 Active  2022-11-02  2
111 Active  2022-11-03  3
111 Active  2022-11-04  4
111 Active  2022-11-05  Z
```

Comment: That's a pretty neat trick with JSON, John..  Thanks for posting it!